# How to order baremetal without public NICs through SL API

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

We used to order baremetals by package as below:

```
server_order = {
    'complexType': 'SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Hardware_Server',
    'quantity': 1,
    'hardware':{"primaryNetworkComponent"..., "primaryBackendNetworkComponent"},
    'location': dal05,
    'packageId': xxx
}

server_container = {
    'complexType': 'SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Hardware_Server',
    'quantity': 1,
    'hardware': {"primaryNetworkComponent"..., "primaryBackendNetworkComponent"},
    'location': dal05,
    'packageId': xxx,
    'prices': {....}
}
```

Now we want the baremetals to be ordered without public NICs. What do we need to do besides removing the `primaryNetworkComponent` from `hardware`?
Also do we need SL to make changes in the package we are using? Or do we have to change to other packages?

Answer (score 0):

Setting hardware´s primary and primaryBackend components won´t define the public nics, they are mostly used to define the vlan or subnet before provisioning.

To order servers with private nic only, you would need the proper item price Id for “Private Network Uplink“ which is related to the "port_speed" categoryCode property, and item price for  “0 GB Bandwidth Allotment ” more related to bandwidth property..

I suggest using a object filter to return only the item prices required, for example:
Method GET

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/ SoftLayer_Product_Package/[packageId]/getItemPrices?objectFilter={"itemPrices": {"item":{"keyName":{"operation" :"*=BPS_PRIVATE_NETWORK_UPLINK"}}}}

https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/ SoftLayer_Product_Package/[packageId]/getItemPrices?objectFilter={"itemPrices": {"item":{"keyName":{"operation":"BANDWIDTH_0_GB"}}}}
```

For more information, see below:

https://softlayer.github.io/article/understanding-ordering/